# Drag and drop in QTreeWidget with custom class (Error :Qvariant::save)

Tags: qt, c++11, qtreewidget, qvariant

my problem is the following :
I want to use a drag and drop in my QTreeWidget. My QtreeWidgetItem have the following flags `Enabled | selectable |Drag | Drop.`

It works for an item but don't for the rest (Error Qvariant::Save invalid type to save)

It's because we do some `: setdata(QVariant::fromvalue<...`

I understand since I want to use custom data,  I need to make QVariant understand my class, and for this I need my class to have a  default constructor, a copy constructor , a destructor, and 2 operator overlord << and >>.

`friend QDataStream & operator << (QDataStream &arch, const MyClass & object)`

After I need `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyClass)` and register my operator with :

`qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<MyClass>("MyClass")`

But I can't get it work. (still Error Qvariant::Save invalid type to save)

I need help to understand where everything goes.
My overloads operators are defined in my class (.H)

Should my Q_DECLARE_METATYPE be declared at the end of my class? (.h) will there be problem because somme class inherit from it? or because it have pure function?

I know many people use the qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators in the main but I can't do that, can I use it elsewhere (in the constructor of one my class or this will cause problem (like multiple declaration or multiple call like the connect functiun))

The error never change , is this normal or should Qt say to me "it recognizes the class I want to save but it doesn't everything needed"?

---

Ok i answered some of my question :
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE dosn't need to be in the .H (right now work with my .cpp)
You can use your qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators in the constructor (as a connect)
When QT reconise your class it will display another message (right now my problem is my class is an abstract class)

I'm trying to make it work with my current architecture

```
MyClass (Abstract)
  - MyClassTemplate : MyClass
      -MyClassA : MyClassTemplate<MyClassA>
      -MyClassB : MyClassTemplate<MyClassB>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it.
you can use an easy trick.
create a struct that has a pointer to the class you want to pass, and had operator << and >> in that class.
Q_Dclare_Metatype(your struct)
don't forget to qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators your struct

Since your class element is never destroyed you can just pass a pointer to it without any risk, and since you declared what type you will pass, qt accept it
(because when i was just apssing void * or other pointer type, qt reconisez that it had a specific type and would'nt work.

Hope it'll help you if you have the same problem